# Show Percentage In The Piechart As A Field

Tags: views, charts

I have a piechart which displays the attendance ratio.
It shows present percentage and absent percentage.
I want the present percentage as a field in a view.
To display the piechart,I am using the following modules
1.Views
2.Charts
3.Google Chart Tools

Comment: which module you are using?

Comment: charts and graphs and google charts

Comment: There is no Drupal module named "google charts" ("Charts and Graphs" does exist though). Are you talking about "Google Chart Tools" or any of the google charts engines (libraries), used in modules such as "Charts" or "Chart"? Please EDIT your question to add the appropriate module links to clarify this. Also, the "view" you mentioned, is that a view created with the "Views" module? Charting in Drupal land has lots of variations, so please make sure to use correct terminology and module names to avoid unclear questions.

Comment: Kindly take a look at the question now.